# Can I get each field in a returned TABLE inside a SELECT?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function which returns a table.

```
ordersum(from_date DATE, limit_date DATE) RETURNS TABLE (antal BIGINT, kundkategori text)
```

In my SELECT I call the function:

```
SELECT start_date,end_date,
ordersum(first_day(start_date),last_day(end_date))
from table
```

Now the result looks like this:

```
startdate,end_date,ordersum
2015-01-01,2016-01-01,(1,"single order")
```

Can I get each field in the table in my select result?
I can not call the function twice as it is very heavy.

```
startdate, end_date,antal,customer_category
2015-01-01,2016-01-01,1,"single order"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.start_date startdate, t.end_date, 
    os.antal quantity, os.kundkategori ordersum
from _table t
cross join lateral ordersum(first_day(start_date),last_day(end_date)) os;
```

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns a table, should be used like a table:

```
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       os.*
from table 
  cross join ordersum(first_day(start_date),last_day(end_date)) as os
```